# jQuery current element index if has class

Tags: jquery

so my code generates like this (when click a it adds active class to current):

```
<div>

<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#" class="active"></a>
<a href="#"></a>

... 

</div>
```

how can I grab active a tags index?

Comment: It's *really worth* spending an hour reading through [the API](http://api.jquery.com). It literally only takes that long, and it saves you hours of time...

Comment: Further to what @T.J.Crowder said, even a couple of minutes reading through just the names of all the jQuery methods and selectors (as shown on the [first page of the API doco](http://api.jquery.com/)) will give you a leg up. If you have more time that same page does have descriptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

`$("a.active").index()`

Example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dvirazulay/V25un/